# Avoid scrollbar from print in yii

Tags: css, yii

In my Yii web application, I am using divToPrint for take print out of a div contents. In div having one class table-responsive for responsive table. Because of this class displayed scroll bar. When I am taking print out of this div, color of this scroll bar also present in that print. How to avoid that scroll bar from print out. For print the below function is used,

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById(divName);
    var popupWin = window.open('', '', 'width=300,height=300');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">');
    popupWin.document.write('<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl ?>/css/assets/css/minified/ccebootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    popupWin.document.write('<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl ?>/css/assets/css/minified/core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    popupWin.document.write('<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl ?>/css/reportcardstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
    popupWin.document.write(divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Yii, as it's PHP framework.

Use css `overflow: visible;` on element that contains scrollbar.